# React-Native ios App crashes without report

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I'm building an iOS app using React Native and trying to get it testable on phones.

If I plug my phone into the computer and "build" directly to the phone, the app is built correctly and opens/operates correctly, no problem.

But if I try to archive it and send it to phones using iTunes Connect's TestFlight or Fabric with Crashlytics, the app crashes immediately upon opening. It briefly shows the launch screen, but no more.

Moreover, there are no crash reports -- in TestFlight, in Crashlytics, or in XCode, once I plug the phone back in. So I'm operating in the dark here, without any information on what's breaking. Haven't been able to find a similar issue online, so I figured I'd just ask. Any ideas what could be going wrong?

Please let me know if there's any code or other data you might need to see. Some of it's confidential, but I'll try to post an approximate version.

Comment: I've not heard of this issue yet either. Am I correct to assume you've updated your AppDelegate.m to use the bundle? Assuming I am, curious which RN version you're on. Just as a sanity check, maybe try building a new fresh app and make sure that works as expected. Then, trial and error, adding sketchy bits to it until it breaks. sucks, but that's what comes to mind straight off.

Comment: Ha yeah. That's exactly what I decided to do. It does seem to be something about my app, even though there are no crash reports, as a fresh app works fine, as does paring my app down to a single Hello World page.

Comment: In that case, I don't think you're going to find much help here without sharing your code. Unfortunately TestFlight and Crashlytics will only tell you when there's a crash on the native side. You'll have to try something like https://getsentry.com/, https://trackjs.com/ or similar to get the JS crash report.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As Chris Geirman suggested, the problem was a JavaScript error. I'm not sure people with similar problems will find this thread, but in case they do, here is the weird error that was occurring.

I had created a simple ORM system, with a BaseModel and a bunch of models that inherited from it. The BaseModel constructor looked like this:

```
  constructor(props = {}, relations = {}) {
    Object.keys(props).forEach((k) => {
      // Save props to object
      this[k] = props[k];
    });

    this.relations = relations;
    this.className = this.constructor.name;
  }
```

That last line was the problem. On my local simulator and if I build the app to my phone by plugging it in, this works fine. As in, if a Message model inherits from BaseModel, calling `var msg = new Message(data, relations); msg.className` returns `Message`.

But something about bundling/archiving/sending the app through TestFlight or Fabric.io minifies and *uglifies* the JavaScript, such that the class names are changed. So instead, if I do this -- `var msg = new Message(data, relations); msg.className` -- I'll get back a random variable name, something like 't'.

This was a problem in my app, because my home page contained a switch statement that worked off of the className:

```
iconContent() {
  return {
    Message: {
      icon: <Image style={styles.feedItemIconImage} source={ require('../assets/img/icon_message.png') } />,
      color: c.grass
    }, ...
  }[this.props.className] // from the model item
}
```

But `'Message'` wasn't, as expected, the value of `this.props.className` -- `'t'` was. And so, if I were to try to tunnel into, say, the `color` value, I'd hit an error, because I was trying to access the `color` property of `null`.

Why that didn't report, I don't know (I followed Chris's suggestions and installed Sentry, but it still seemed not to report that error).

But that's what was going on. Minification/uglification occurred **only** when I installed the app on a phone via TestFlight/Fabric, and that's why the app only crashed in those conditions.

Hope this saves anyone running into a similar bug from tearing out their hair.

Comment: Having the same problem as you. How did you track down the issue? Just trial and error?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately. I narrowed the issue down to one file by just commenting out huge sections of the app, and then I just printed the data to the page instead of going through any of the rendering steps. WAY easier with Fabric.io than with TestFlight, cause the latter takes about 100x more time per distribution. It was still super tedious, but not TOO bad.

Comment: Great, thanks! So, by using Fabric.io does it cut out the need for TestFlight altogether?

Comment: Well, I'm a special case -- I'm building this app out for a client with a number of people who will want to see it as it progresses. Fabric.io is great for that -- I can push out versions to particular people easily and quickly. I have no sense of how/whether it feeds into the app store eventually. Haven't looked into that at all. Will cross that bridge when I get to it, but Fabric is a great tool for internal prototyping/sharing.

Comment: @Sasha was it a crash? Or the app just quit? I have a similar problem after adding notifications to the iOS app.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to share my own experience of production stage crash, whereas everything worked fine in development stage.

I had the similar problem which caused by the **Reactotron** logger. Since I'm not bundling it in production stage, a single line of console.tron.log crashed my app with full stealth. *(Its kinda my fault, since I didn't give a damn about my linter with 'no-console' setting)*

Here's the code snippet I introduce in my root level file, root.js.

```
  if (__DEV__) {
     ...
     console.tron = Reactotron;
     ...
  }
```

Hope somebody finds this before wasting time figuring out what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you still have this problem - but if you do, I'd recommend checking out Bugsnag for [react native error reporting](https://docs.bugsnag.com/platforms/react-native/) - which reports crashes in both the JavaScript layer as well as the native layers (java/cocoa).

One of the harder problems to solve in react native crash reporting (as Sasha mentioned) is restoring the original stack traces when using minification and/or obfuscation - this is handled in Bugsnag by providing full support for JS source maps, as well as iOS symbolication and Android Proguard support at the native layers.

Let me know if this helps - I'm a founder @ Bugsnag

Comment: I am having the same issue as the OP, but i am using Bugsnag. For some reason the errors are not being reported.

Comment: I've been having trouble investigating a crash-on-launch situation that only affects Release (same as OP). 
Crashlytics gives me a minified (and unhelpful) stacktrace. 
Bugsnag and Sentry dashboards come up empty.

Even though it appears to be a JS exception it seems like the crash occurs before the Bugsnag/Sentry handler loads.

Comment: downvoted because you're advertising for your company