# iOS React Native App Crashing on Archive Only

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, testflight

I'm using React Native and love it. I have an app that works perfectly locally in development and also release.

However, I find when I archive the app and use either Fabric or Testflight, the app wont open and crashes every time. I have a feeling it has something to do with the minifying process, but when I only reference an image on my screen, it still crashes.

Has anyone else experience this? What's a solution?

Comment: If the app is running well both in development and release configs, it's probably something wrong with your adhoc certificate / provisioning profile

Comment: @Bienemann thanks! Would removing and adding a new one be better? Right now I can upload to testflight no problem, no errors, but then it won't open after installing.

Comment: Are you sure the device you are testing on is added to the provisioning profile you are using? Check that first and it might save you the trouble of creating a new one from scratch.

Comment: Yeah, I tried checking it and found that it is indeed there. I'll try to delete and add a new one. I wouldn't think it would be the issue as test flight doesn't need them, but willing to see. I honestly thought it was a problem with the JS minification.

Comment: Did you ever figure out the problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35785747/react-native-ios-app-crashes-without-report

Comment: Have you tried run your project in production mode from xcode?  You will see the error logs there.