# react-native app is crashing on launch screen

Tags: ios, react-native, crash

When I'm testing my app on develop mode, everything is ok, but when I'm sending a test flight version of app to the app store my app is crashing at Launch Screen and I have to open the app from recent list or open multiple times until the app is running.
I really don't know what is my problem and how can I fix that.

Comment: Do you have any development environment tools? Such as reactotron?

Comment: @EnieJakiro No, I don't

Comment: I don't know what may go wrong with your code since you gave no detail at all. But you can check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35785747/react-native-ios-app-crashes-without-report/42056288#42056288

Comment: @EnieJakiro Thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using react-native-navigation for my app. 
After hours I found my problem. 
In my `AppDelgate.m` I forgot to remove some line of codes depending on [this source](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/blob/master/example/ios/example/AppDelegate.m)
.

So after updating the `AppDelegate.m` file and creating a new bundle, Everything is ok.