# react-native iOS release build fails to launch

Tags: react-native

I am having an issue with my release iOS build of my react-native application.

Everything works as expected when using the debug scheme, but as soon I change to a release scheme only the initial and automatic first launch works. If I close and reopen the app, it immediately shuts down.

Do anybody have experienced similar things ? or have a suggestion for how to debug this sort of issue?

Any help is much appreciated!

Edit: short video showing the behaviour: https://vid.me/6kkB

AppDeletegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
@import GooglePlaces;
@import GoogleMaps;

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  NSURL *jsCodeLocation;

  [GMSPlacesClient provideAPIKey:@"AIzaSyDHHSswYLWfcoKIjwSWDecBqib6r1fDMsc"];
  [GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"AIzaSyDHHSswYLWfcoKIjwSWDecBqib6r1fDMsc"];
  [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                           didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];

  // Dev
  jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index.ios" fallbackResource:nil];

  // Release
  //jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];

  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                      moduleName:@"get"
                                               initialProperties:nil
                                                   launchOptions:launchOptions];
  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
            openURL:(NSURL *)url 
            options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options {

  BOOL handled = [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
    openURL:url
    sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
    annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]
  ];
  // Add any custom logic here.
  return handled;
}



@end
```

Comment: You mean app works allright the first time? If not see if you are building the app as a bundle instead of fetching js from localhost in Appdelegate.m

Comment: Yes. The app works right the first time. However, I just noticed that running the app using 'react-native run-iso' produces the immediate crash on first launch. Only using 'build and run' in xCode allows me to run the app perfectly fine _the_first_time.

Comment: Well then build the app in debug mode and check whether if it is throwing any error in console (chrome debugging or xcode) even if it is not crashing

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any errors or warnings. Btw, the same behaviour is present in debug mode..

Comment: Added a link to a video showing the behaviour.

Comment: Try turning on js remote debugging and see if it shows anything when the app crashes. Also share your code in Appdelegate.m file

Comment: You may need to debug your app file by file.. This thread may help you http://stackoverflow.com/q/35785747/6423570

Comment: Added appdeletegate.m

Answer (score 0):

Something that works for me when I experience that problem, is simply:

- clean project
- close project, quit xCode
- restart xCode, Build & Run

And keep an eye on the packager terminal.. sometimes it hangs or doesn't even start. which then can be manually started by using `npm start`

Comment: Thank your very much for your suggestion. Unfortunately it did not help in this case.